# Read in Data from MongoDB directly to a D3 geojson Graphic

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, d3.js, geojson

I have a a mongodb setup that I access through the python library pymongo and I'm looking for an efficient way to import my data into a format I can access through the java script library D3. I realize that MongoDB uses bisons to store data, but I'm looking to create automated data visualizations, obviously based on my pymongo query parameters.

Specifically my data represents a flow between two cities and a weight for that edge.

```
Data{ {'from': 'Seattle'},
      {'to': 'Spokane'},
      {'weight':8}}
```

I have a geojson file and the visualizations I want to create on my map, but simply need a way to bring the data into JS while keeping somewhat similar format. Ideally it would look be similar to a tuple, something like:

```
('Seattle','Spokane',8)
```

Thanks in adavnace!

Comment: Are you asking how to get this format from MongoDB? Convert it in Python? Convert in Javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I didnt specify that, I don't really have preference as to where this conversion takes place. I suppose python would work the best. I'm open to all suggestions though.

Comment: With D3 all you need is call [`d3.values()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_values).

Comment: I mean that works, but I'm looking for a pymongo driver that will allow me to automatically format the data in whichever language I'm using. I want one script that cleans the data and creates a graphic.

Comment: You may want to clarify that in the question and retag as appropriate.